# Add Widget to the a Panel at first Position?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

If you want to add a Widget to a lets say FlowPanel you have to do the following:

```
@UiField
FlowPanel panel;

Widget widget; // some widget

panel.add(widget)
```

This appends the widget to the panel, which means it comes a last position of the panel's child Widgets.

I.e.:

```
<div>
 <div class="w1" />
 <div class="w2" />
 <div class="w3" />
 <div class="widget" />
</div>
```

**Is there any way to get a newly inserted widget a the first position, i.e., make a prepend, without removing all the other widgets first?**

**Is there any way to get a newly inserted widget a a certain index within the parent?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,

```java
flowPanel.insertWidget(widget, pos);
```

Use `pos = 0` to insert at the first position.